# How to find X,Y coordinate given an angle and distance from the origin?

Tags: coordinate-systems

Lets say, the distance from origin is 2.8284271247462 and angle is 45 degrees from North (i.e. +ve y axis) in anticlockwise direction

so this means that answer should be -2,2 , because according to pythagoras that is the answer, if a = 2 and b =2 then c = 2.8284271247462, simple pythagoras.

Is there a way to find X,Y from Given Angle and Length ?

More examples:

```
if Angle is 315, and distance is 2.8284271247462, then new X,Y = (2,2)
if Angle is 135, and distance is 2.8284271247462, then new X,Y = (-2,-2)
if Angle is 225, and distance is 2.8284271247462, then new X,Y = (2,-2)
```

Diagram:
[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccPqh.png)

Comment: Are you familiar with polar coordinates?

Comment: these are normal coordinate system with 4 quadrants

Comment: Google "polar coordinates" and you'll find what you need to know.

Comment: I googled, I didn't understand anything. Also I can't find for my specific case anywhere on google.

Comment: https://www.mathsisfun.com/polar-cartesian-coordinates.html

Comment: What is missing from your text and your picture also is a firm grasp of the four standard symbols $x,y,r,\theta.$ Well, $x$ and $y$ you have used, but you need to study the mathisfun link above, I say, to learn the relationships.

Comment: it is coming incorrect using that link, when angle is 45 degrees and distance is 2.8284271247462, then x, y should come -2,2 respectively but with those equations it is not coming, distance * cos(45) = 2.8284271247462 * 0.52532198881 = 1.48583496238, it is impossible for x to be 1.48, it should be -2,2

Comment: i think your problem is measuring angle from "North", as in navigation. Trigonometry is not set up that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $r$ is distance from the origin and $\theta$ is angle, then
$$
x=r\cos \theta
$$
and
$$
y=r \sin \theta.
$$

Comment: it is giving me incorrect value, when angle is 45 degrees and distance is 2.8284271247462, then x, y should come -2,2 respectively but with those equations it is not coming, distance * cos(45) = 2.8284271247462 * 0.52532198881 = 1.48583496238, it is impossible for x to be 1.48, it should be -2,2

Comment: This formula works if you measure angle from east, the positive x-axis. To measure angle from north you would do $y=r\cos \theta$ and $x=-r\sin \theta.$ Also, your $\cos(45)$ is off. Should be .707... Perhaps you are calculating with radians instead of degrees.

Comment: Ah that is what I was missing, I was using sin(45), had to sin(radians), thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Let $X=\mathbb{R}^2$ with the standart topology, given a point $A=(x,y)\in X$ you can write it in terms of the distance from the origen $O=(0,0)$ to the point $A$ namely $r$ and the angle counterclockwise with the $x$ axis namely $\theta$.

The relation is the following:
$$x=r\cos \theta , \, y=r\sin \theta$$

where $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $\theta=\arctan\left( \frac{y}{x}\right)$ you can verify it drawing a point $A$ in the plane, identify the lenght form $O$ to $A$ and drawing the perpendicular segment to the $x$ axis that pass through by $A$ and look the triangle that is formed  and apply the Pythagorean theorem to see the relations.

Given a explicit $\theta$ and $r$ you can get the point $A=(x,y)$ only making the substitution in the above expression for $x$ and $y$.